# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from my External HDD to my Laptop Internal HDD

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, 18.04, external-hdd

I have to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to my Laptop, I can Install it from USB Pen Drive or any CD/DVD but the problem is I don't have that, but I have my USB External HDD, **So I want to use my External HDD to install Ubuntu into my laptop internal HDD**.
**I used Rufus,UNetbootin, EaseUS Partition Master etc tools to make my External HDD bootable to format my laptop internal HDD, But unfortunately none of these methods worked for me**, Currently I am using windows 10 in this laptop, I tried many tutorials and googled it but no luck. I found some similar question on this website but none of them are answered, So lastly I am writing this question.
So please help to make my External HDD bootable So that i can install Ubuntu on my Laptop's internal HDD.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: does the external HDD have any data on it you want to retain?

Comment: No, I don't have any data on my external HDD, I don't have any issue to format it if required.

Comment: also, are you accessing your laptop boot menu, or have you changed your BIOS/UEFI to boot from USB drive first? what make is your laptop?

Comment: I can access my laptop boot menu, currently boot manager is configured to GPT file system,
I have changed boot menu as first boot from usb-external hdd, then usb and after that boot manager

Comment: BIOS / UEFI: is Secure boot mode on/off? is CSM/Legacy mode on/off?

Comment: on your boot menu does the USB HDD show up? If yes, do you get any error message when selected?

Comment: Internal HDD file system is gpt and Legacy mode is disabled and secure boot mode is on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78423/discussion-between-broadsworde-and-sabir-ali).

Comment: Is your external HDD formated in NTFS, EXT4 or FAT64? Because it can be a problem it's in NTFS